# Haskell - Get the index of the first occurrence in a list of strings

Tags: string, list, haskell, find, character

I have a list of strings like the following:

```haskell
[ "aaa", "aaa", "aba", "aaa"]
```

I want to make a function that returns the first position of the list where there is an item containing the character 'b'. How can I do it in Haskell?

Comment: What has been your approach so far?  Can you write a function to test if a character appears in a string?  For example, `contains "aba" 'b'` would return `True`.

Comment: @bheklilr As far as I could see, this function is deprecated. Instead isInfixOf can be used, which in this case `isInfixOf "b" "aba"` would return `True`

Comment: I was actually unaware that there was a `contains` function already, I was intending that you write your own =P  I'm assuming that this is an assignment and it's supposed to help teach you about working with recursion on linked lists, in which case you should implement everything you can to learn as much as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that will do what you want:

```
getIndexWithb = findIndex ('b' `elem`)
```

You will need to import `Data.List` to make this work.  Also note that this function returns type `Maybe Int` for the case that `'b'` never appears in any of the strings.

---

Usage:

```
> getIndexWithb [ "aaa", "aaa", "aba", "aaa"]
Just 2
```

Answer (score 2):

[The List Utilities chapter of the Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/list.html) describes a function `findIndex` which finds the index of the first element of a list that satisfies an arbitrary predicate.  It can be implemented as

```
findIndex p xs =
  case [ i | (x, i) <- zip xs [0..], p x ] of
    [] -> Nothing
    e:_ -> Just e
```

With that, you can find the first element of the list that contains `'b'` with

```
findIndex ('b'`elem`) ["aaa", "aaa", "aba", "aaa"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask for the first *position* so I'm not clear whether you want an index value or the actual value. Here's a function that gives you a tuple containing both the index and the value at that index.

```haskell
import Data.Maybe

firstOccurrenceOf :: Char -> [String] -> Maybe (Int, String)
firstOccurrenceOf c list =
  listToMaybe $ filter (elem c . snd) $ zip [0..] list
```

`listToMaybe` provides a safe alternative to `head` which will return `Nothing` instead of crashing on an empty list.

Comment: You can use `listToMaybe` instead of `safeHead`.

Comment: @chi - `elem c` is of type `String -> Bool`. It may be due to the fact that `elem` is usually used in infix form that you're thinking it should accept a `Char`.

Comment: @ChadGilbert - I just need the index value but this is great. As @is7s says `listToMaybe` can be used instead of safeHead. Thanks!

Comment: @ChadGilbert Indeed `elem c :: String -> Bool`, but `filter` will pass a `Char` to that, which looks wrong. Am I missing something?

Comment: @chi - `filter` would be passing a `String` to `elem c` if its input was a list of strings, but in my example I'm passing a zipped list of ints and strings. It [compiles and works as advertised](http://rextester.com/YDB37923).

Comment: @ChadGilbert You're correct. I missed a `[]` in my head. Thank you.